# Check and do animation when new Ajax data pushed in?

Tags: jquery, ajax, real-time

I'm pulling data from the database using Ajax. What would be the best way to do some animations or notification when the new data(value) is pulled in? For instance if the value of availability changes then blink or highlight that particular .box div 3 times.

Ajax:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                //function the get data from database
                function getRealData(){
                    $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'test_api.php', 
                    data: "", dataType: 'json', 
                    success: function(rows) { 

                    var text = '';

                        for (var i in rows) { 

                            var row = rows[i]; 

                            var availability = row[3]; 

                            var hostName = row[2];

                            var intranet = row[6];

                            var timeRespons = row[4]; 



                            //console.log(availability);

                            text += '<div class="box"><b>availability: </b><span class="av ' + (availability == 1 ? 'avHighlight' : '') + '">'+availability+'</span>' + 
        '<b> hostName: </b>'+hostName+ '<b> intranet: </b>'+intranet+'<b> timeResponse:</b>'+timeRespons;
    text += '<br/ ></div>';


                        }
                        $("#content").html(text);       


                    }
                });
                }

                //this refreshes data every 2seconds
                setInterval(getRealData, 2000);

                //call the function to display data
                getRealData();


            });

  </script>
```

HTML Output:

```
availability: 0 hostName: aaa intranet: ttt timeResponse:0.124
availability: 0 hostName: qqq intranet: ttt timeResponse:0.064
availability: 0 hostName: www intranet: ttt timeResponse:0.303
availability: 0 hostName: rrr intranet: ttt timeResponse:0.019
availability: 0 hostName: eee intranet: ttt timeResponse:0.025
availability: 0 hostName: ggg intranet: ttt timeResponse:0.158
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use jQuery.animate for animation.

Comment: i know how to use jQuery animation. it is just that I don't know how to check for new data and then do animation based on new data.

Comment: r u  trying to check if availability=1? or new availabilityvalue=old value ?

Comment: @Arunu yes, I would like to check or compare new value to the old value, and then based on that do some animation. I guess it has to be outside the "setinterval" otherwise it will do animation constantly :(

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line by one of the following.

```
$("#content").html(text);
```

To

```
$("#content").html(text).hide().show("easeIn");
$("#content").html(text).hide().fadeIn("slow");
$("#content").html(text).hide().slideDown("slow");
```

For more animation, you can visit http://www.easings.net

Comment: no, this is constantly blinking no matter if the new data is pulled or not because it is within set-interval. I need to check for new data and the do animation but only to the new data,.

Comment: Compare your response like this. if($("#content").html() != text) then write that animation lines

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global variable `preData` outside ur function which will contain the previous availability value.Since all div has same `class="box"` we cant apply javascript animation to that class.We will have to use `id` then.From what I understood ,The function `getRealData` occurs every 2 sec I think change in background color will act as animation.Pls try this code and let  me know.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

  var preData;

 //function the get data from database
 function getRealData() {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'test_api.php',
         data: "",
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (rows) {

             var text = '';

             for (var i in rows) {

                 var row = rows[i];

                 var availability = row[3];
                 var hostName = row[2];
                 var intranet = row[6];
                 var timeRespons = row[4];
                 if(preData==''){
                 preData=availability; 
                 }
                 //console.log(availability);

                 text += '<div ';
                if(availability!=preData){
                 //set background color green if availability value changes
                  text+='style="background:green;"';
                 }

                 text+= 'class="box"><b>availability: </b><span class="av ' + (availability == 1 ? 'avHighlight' : '') + '">' + availability + '</span>' +
                         '<b> hostName: </b>' + hostName + '<b> intranet: </b>' + intranet + '<b> timeResponse:</b>' + timeRespons;
                     text += '<br/ ></div>';

                 //store new data to preData
                  preData=availability;

                 }
             $("#content").html(text);


         }
     });
 }

 //this refreshes data every 2seconds
 setInterval(getRealData, 2000);

 //call the function to display data
 getRealData();


 });
```

Comment: this kind of works if the value changes from 0 to 1, but how we make this fadeIn fade Out every time the value changes?